# Converting a variable user input float into an array of characters in C?

Tags: c, string, printf, double

my goal in the program is to prompt a user for a value of money (float) within a certain range to use in another function. However, the other function seems much easier to accomplish using an array of characters as the input. I have looked into using sprintf and snprintf, but am not sure how/if these can be implemented with a variable input instead of a constant.

The function this number will be passed to needs to convert the number to written words. Example: 1150.50 = One thousand one hundred fifty dollars and fifty cents.

Here is the segment of code I am trying to implement;

```
do {

        puts("Please enter the amount of the paycheck, this must be from 0$ to 10000$:  \n");
        scanf("%.2f", entered_amount);

        if (entered_amount < 0.00 && entered_amount > 10000.00) {
        printf("This is not a valid amount, please try again!   \n\n");

        }

    } while (entered_amount < 0.00 && entered_amount > 10000.00);

    sprintf(amount, "%f", entered_amount);                  
    //Trying to convert a float entered by the user to an array of characters to use in the number_to_word function!
    printf("%s", amount);
```

Where entered_amount will be a user input float, and amount would be an 
array of char's. Ex:
5555.55 = {"5,5,5,5,.,5,5"}

I appreciate all help and feedback, thanks!

Comment: 1) `entered_amount < 0.00 && entered_amount > 10000.00)` --> `entered_amount < 0.00 || entered_amount > 10000.00)`

Comment: Ah good catch on that, thanks!

Comment: `scanf("%.2f", entered_amount);`...emmm..missing a `&` somewhere?

Comment: This (with the adviced fixes) loops forever when first entering a negative number and then something that's not a number.

Answer (score 0):

If `amount` is char array of sufficient size, then after calling sprintf, you have your desired structure.

```
sprintf(amount, "%f", entered_amount);
```

You can print it easily by `printf` as you tried.

```
printf("%s", amount);   //Print entire array
//Print char by char
size_t i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(amount); i++)
    printf("%c", amount[i]);
```

---

The problem is more with your if statement with checking for range.

```
if (entered_amount < 0.00 && entered_amount > 10000.00) {
```

This will never be executed. Use this instead:

```
if (entered_amount < 0.00 || entered_amount > 10000.00) {
```

---

When reading float, you should do it by pointer (Check additional *&* character):

```
scanf("%.2f", &entered_amount);
```

Comment: Hmm, I fixed the || instead of && in the while loop, as well as the &entered_amount. The real problem is with sprintf(amount, "%f", entered_amount);, when I printf("%s", amount) it just prints 0.00000..regardless of the value entered.